# SQL query : finding a word in a shapefile

Tags: qgis, sql, query, dbmanager

I have a punctual shapefile containing the name of geographic locations (attribute 'name')

Using DB Manager of Qgis, I would like create an SQL query to find, within the shape, the name of a location and, and therefore its point.
I would like to find the name of the location even by writing only one part.

For example:
The name of location is 'Torretta'. Just writing "Torr", I would like to find all the locations that contain the word "Torr" (without considering the upper case and lower case letters).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One example working with QGIS Alaska dataset:

```
SELECT * 
FROM "airports"
WHERE lower("NAME")  LIKE lower('%Big%')
```

- FROM: your shapefile layer shown as a Virtual Layer
- "NAME" is "name" in your case
- '%Big%' would be '%Torr%'

[image]

Hitting [Load now!] button (at lower right corner), selected Big Lake and Big Mountain AFS appear as a new `QueryLayer`.

[image]

**EDIT** To narrow down the selection by using both "name" and "town", please add `AND` keyword.

```
SELECT * 
FROM "your_shapefile_layer"
WHERE lower("name") LIKE lower('%Torr%') AND lower("town") LIKE lower('%potenza%')
```

Comment: next step: in the same shape I also have an attribute "town". I would like add to quary both the search by "name" and by "town". For example:  searching only the location 'Torretta' of town "potenza"

Comment: Thanks @GiuseppeCillis Please see the bottom of my answer (marked **EDIT**). Please let me know if it does not work.

Comment: Yes!! It work perfectly !!